# Converting Decimal Number to Binary Number using stack

Tags: c++, struct, stack

I am trying to convert a decimal number to binary number using stacks and I have to use structs.

Now from my understanding of structs, we can have member functions in them. And stack follows a LIFO strategy.

We can create a stack by making a struct, declaring some members, and have some functions to initialize and work on these members.

So, I tried declaring a struct with above mentioned things and my understanding, but I still do not seem to get the concept right. I believe it is an error on my part. But reading forums still does not help as we have not been taught classes yet and on every forum, structs and classes are intermixed.

Here is my code so far, any help and guidance regarding the concept and logic would be much appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bin{
int num[15];
int ci;

void init()
{
    ci = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < 15;i++)
        num[i] = -1;
}

void push(int n)
{
    num[ci] = n;
    ci++;
}
int pop()
{
    int temp = num[--ci];
    num[ci] = -1;
    return temp;
}
};

int main()
{
int inp, count = 0;
bin var;
cout << "Enter a decimal number to convert into binary: ";
cin >> inp;

while (inp != 0)
{
    int rem = inp % 2;
    cout << "rem= " << rem << endl;
    inp /= 2;
    cout << "inp= " << inp << endl;
    var.push(rem);
    count++;
}
cout << "\nYour binary is: ";
while (count != 0)
{
    cout << var.pop();
    count--;
}

return 0;
}
```

I tried my best to find the mistakes but couldn't. So,in the end I simply used arrays and implemented the code as follows

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void push(int bin[], int n, int &ci);
void init(int bin[], int &count, int &ci);
int pop(int bin[], int &ci);
void display(int bin[], int &count, int &ci);
void findBinary(int bin[], int &count, int&ci, int &inp);

int main()
{
int inp, count, ci;
int bin[20];
char c = '\0';

init(bin,count,ci);

    cout << "Enter a decimal number to convert into binary: ";
    cin >> inp;

    findBinary(bin, count, ci, inp);
    display(bin, count, ci);

return 0;
}

void init(int bin[], int &count, int &ci)
{
count = 0;
ci = 0;

for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++)
    bin[i] = -1;
}

int pop(int bin[], int &ci)
{
    int temp = bin[--ci];
    return temp;
}

void push(int bin[], int n, int &ci)
{
    bin[ci] = n;
    ci++;
}

void display(int bin[], int &count, int &ci)
{
    cout << "\nYour binary is: ";
    while (count != 0)
    {
        cout << pop(bin, ci);
        count--;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void findBinary(int bin[], int &count, int&ci, int &inp)
{
    while (inp != 0)
    {
        int rem = inp % 2;
        inp /= 2;
        push(bin, rem, ci);
        count++;
    }
}
```

So my questions are:
 1. When we write a function within a struct, does the function runs when we create a struct type object?
 2. Is the method I used to implement stack using struct in the first example correct?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but I didn't use that code as it wasn't compiling. But I still need to replace the value in the pop function so as to delete the value (-1 is assumed as deleted).

Comment: Your code in the first example compile and runs fine (and correctly) for me. Expand on "I still do not seem to get the concept right".

Comment: On second note, my original pop function is correct. ci is originally pointing to an empty index to enter data.

Comment: Regarding the concept, the functions written in the struct, do they run when I declare a struct type variable? If so then the first code should not work.

Comment: No - the functions in the struct will only run when you explicitly call them - see my answer.

Comment: Sorry, the code did compile successfully (I was confusing this one with its another variation) but it did not give correct answers. It runs fine until the push() call in while() in the first iteration, and then stops responding prompting an error.

Comment: Edit your answer to include a [MCVE].

Comment: while (inp != 0)
{
    int rem = inp % 2;
    cout << "rem= " << rem << endl;
    inp /= 2;
    cout << "inp= " << inp << endl;
    var.push(rem);//The code stops working here
    count++;
}

Comment: The *example* was the relevant part. What input did you provide that caused your program to fail?

Comment: I entered 5 as an input. The code runs until the above mentioned line, after that visual studio gives error: lab4.exe has stopped working.

Comment: This isn't reproducible on my machine or on an [online service](https://ideone.com/DIFbSP). Regardless, this is all off-topic from the actual question stated.

Comment: Your push and pop function should check that they do not go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create an object from a `struct` or `class`, the [**constructor**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) runs - but no other function (so not your `init` function). If you want that to run, you need to call it explicitly:

```
bin var;
var.init();
```

In terms of the implementation of your functions: you should use bounds-checking to ensure that you don't push more items than you can handle, or pop more than are in the queue. Besides that I can't see much wrong with them. Consider using a `std::vector` instead of an array, but as you're just starting to learn about C++, you'll likely cover that later in your course.

---

By the time you're adding constructors to a `struct` though, you may as well switch to using a `class`. In C++, structs and classes are equivalent (with the minor tweak that the default access modifier in a struct is `public`, whereas in classes it's `private`), so don't let that put you off.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do the problem in this way ,I fixed it just like this .

#include

using namespace std;

#define MAX_STACK 10

int top=-1;

struct bin

{

int num[MAX_STACK];

bool isEmpty()

{

return (top < 0);
}

void push(int newItem)
{

// if stack has no more room for
// another item

if (top >= MAX_STACK-1)

cout<<"Stack Overflow!";

else{

++top;

num[top] = newItem;

}

}

int pop()

{

if(top < 0)

{

//top points to nothing i.e stack is empty

cout << "Stack Underflow \n";

return 0;
}

else

{

/*decrement the top pointer and it

points to the next top element in the stack*/

int d = num[top--];

return d;

}

}

};

int main()

{

int value, count = 0;

bin var;

int rem;

cout << "Enter a decimal number to convert into binary: ";

cin >> value;

while (value != 0)

{
rem = value % 2;

cout << "rem= " << rem << endl;

var.push(rem);

count++;

value /= 2;
}

cout << "\nYour binary is: ";

while (count != 0)
{

cout << var.pop();

count--;

}

return 0;

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).